# Declare a variable without datatype

Tags: go, variables

I have a piece of code that needs a variable declaration w/o its type. The variable is assigned a value later and that is an interface. pseudo code will look very similar to this:

```
var client
if some_condn {
   client = ssh.Dial(params)
} else {
   client = my_own_ssh_dial(my_params)
}
session,_ := client.NewSession()
```

The problem is GO does not allow a variable declaration w/o type. Is there any way I can use something like an generic Object (from Java) to default client to start with?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable must have a type in order to use it. The closest thing to an untyped variable would be the type `interface{}`, which is an interface type, but has no methods to call.

Since the goal here is to call the `NewSession` method, declare the variable with an interface containing that method.

```
var client interface {
    NewSession() (*ssh.Session, error)
}
if some_condn {
    client = ssh.Dial(params)
} else {
    client = my_own_ssh_dial(my_params)
}
session, _ := client.NewSession()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty new to Go, but I'll take a stab. If it's wrong, cool. Unfortunately, I don't have enough code from you to actually try and do this - but essentially, you'll need to make your own type `my_own_ssh`, and then add a `Dial` function to it. Then, you'll define an

```
interface Client {
    Dial()
}
```

And then you can define your `client` variable with `var client Client` before the conditional check. You'll also need to create a function `Dial` that has a `my_own_ssh` receiver in order for the interface to work/make sense.

I'm very happy to receive feedback on this answer, because like I said - I'm pretty new to it :)